# Replace the path of an image in XML export

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

I am exporting articles from InDesign to XML to import it on our website.

Now I want to import the images. I put it in a tag in InDesign called "IMG". The standard output without XSL looks like this:

```
<Artikelbild href="file:///K:/customer/flyer/banana.jpg"></Artikelbild>
```

I need it like this:

```
<Artikelbild>banana.jpg</Artikelbild>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Servus,

You can solve it with Regular Expression (GREP) on Indesign, BBEdit or even Dreamweaver. It goes as follows:

```
Find
.+(\w+?\.jpg).+

Change
 <Artikelbild>$1</Artikelbild>
```

Viel Erfolg